# closed form is exact in euclidean space

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-topology, closed-form

Question is to show that $d(f)=0$ for a $0$ form on $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $f$ is a constant function.

See that $$0=df=\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dx_i$$
implies that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=0$ for all $i$.

Let $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$. For this $a$ we have $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a_1+h,a_2,\cdots,a_n)-f(a_1,\cdots,a_n)}{h}=0$$

Seeing this as single variable function and using mean value theorem we see that $f(a_1+p,a_2,\cdots,a_n)=f(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$ for all $p\in\mathbb{R}$

For $p=-a_1$ we have $f(0,a_2,\cdots,a_n)=f(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$

Now, do the same thin for $f(0,x_2,c_3,\cdots,x_n)$ and conclude that
 $f(0,0,\cdots,a_n)=f(0,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$.

Combining with previous result we have  $f(0,0,\cdots,a_n)=f(0,a_2,\cdots,a_n)=f(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$.

Repeating this, we get $f(0,0,\cdots,0)=f(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$. Thus, $f$
 is constant.

Now, i am not sure if i can really use this type of approach and succeed in case of $1$ forms.

Suppose $f$ is a $1$  form and $df=0$ i.e., $f=g_1dx_1+g_2dx_2+\cdots g_ndx_n$ and $df=0$ implies $$0=df=\sum_i d(g_i)\wedge dx_i=\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j}dx_j\wedge dx_i$$

So, we have $$\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j} - \frac{\partial g_j}{\partial x_i}=0$$for all $i,j$.. I am not sure how to use  this...

Note : Credits to above correction goes to user muaddib

Please suggest some hints...

Comment: I don't understand what you want to show/are asking.  You prove a result for $0$ forms, and then start working with $1$ forms.  Are you attempting to show $1$ forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are exact?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Poincar.C3.A9_lemma

Comment: @muaddib : I thought i have written it clearly.. I want to show that closed $1$ forms are exact and in general closed $k$ forms are exact...

Comment: Thank you for clariyfing.  Makes sense given the title.  I think you have an error in your final equations: Suppose $f$ is a $1$  form and $df=0$ i.e., $f=g_1dx_1+g_2dx_2+\cdots g_ndx_n$ and $df=0$ implies 
$$0=df=\sum_i d(g_i)\wedge dx_i=\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j}dx_j\wedge dx_i$$

So, we have $$\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j} - \frac{\partial g_j}{\partial x_i}=0$$for all $i,j$.

Comment: @muaddib : Yes Yes that is a mistake and was by mistake... i will edit.. :)

Comment: @PrahullaKoushik - My two cents for the problem.  I think you will have difficulty trying to argue using this technique.  The poincare lemma holds for contractible domains used, but that assumption isn't used in your argument for $0$ forms.  I don't believe a result like the mean value theorem really relies on the overall topology of the domain (like contractibility), so I think you are going to need to add something to the method.  I can't think of anything that doesn't use something like Stoke's theorem, but that is more the typical proof.

Comment: @muaddib I know that there is something called poincare lemma... This question was asked just after defining exterior differentiation and no stokes theorem was introduced there.. So, I am looking for some basic solution with out using stokes theorem and/or poincare lemma.. You can definitely post proof using stokes theorem.. It would be definitely useful.. :)

Comment: @muaddib : Please share your ideas about this problem using stokes theorem.. It would be useful...

Comment: I believe Poincare lemma would help. Here is some disscusion on $\mathbb{R}^2$. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367343/proving-the-poincare-lemma-for-1-forms-on-mathbbr2

Comment: @FallenApart I could not understand much after seeing that...