# Differential forms and smooth functions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ two smooth functions of the real variables $x$ and $y$. My questions is about the existence of a function $g$ non-zero such that $gf_1dx+gf_2dy$ is the differential of a smooth function. Is this equivalent to find a $g$ such that $(\partial/\partial y)(gf_1)=(\partial/\partial x)(gf_2)$? If this is true, how can I prove the existence of such $g$? Thanks!

Comment: Does $g=0$ work?

Comment: yes if the domain "has no holes".

Answer (score -2):

**Hint:** Existence of differential form is one of the Goal of  [De_Rham_cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology) which investigate for differential form with prescribed properties. and the best appraoch which presented above by **Akaba** comment is  g(x)=0 since it is  smooth function and satisfies the titled differential form .

Comment: Thanks, but sorry I forgot to write that g must be non zero (if not it's trivial!). I just can't understand what the condition for the partial derivates means. It reminds me the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Do you have some hints?

Comment: @AshleyCourtney it means $d(gf_1 dx + gf_2 dy) =0.$ Do you know how to "differentiate" 1-forms?

Comment: Yes, I do. One has $d(df)=(\partial/\partial y)(gf_1)dy\wedge dx+(\partial/\partial x)(gf_2)dx\wedge dy=0$, so $df$ is in the first De Rham cohomology group. But the question remains, how to find a non-trivial $g$? (If it exists).

Comment: @AshleyCourtney Oh you want to *construct* $g$? I thought you just wanted to prove that one exists. The proof of the poincare lemma (that closed forms are exact on star shaped domains) is constructive.  You can find the proof in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, or possibly here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367343/proving-the-poincare-lemma-for-1-forms-on-mathbbr2

Comment: Thank you, I m going to look up!